# How should it work if I want a page to have a theme-roller (more or less like the jQuery themeroller)

Tags: jquery, css, theming

The basic idea is to create a page that gives the user the ability to choose a skin or theme from a menu. When the user selects the desired skin/theme, it should be applied to the page, just like the jquery ui theme roller page.

So, to be more precise, what I am trying to know is how to apply dynamically the style to a page - how to load the css and so forth. On the jquery ui theme roller, is there any javascript triggered after the new set of styles is loaded? (for js positioning or sizing?)

(The answer may be simple as "just create a new style element and set its src"...)

Just to be clear, I don't need the option to let users customize the UI, I want them just to be able to pick from a few pre set styles.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create multiple styles for each them and then use some:

**[jQuery Styleswitcher Widget](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Styleswitcher)**

**Update:**

It seems that links are not working which is strange how such stuff is there on official site, however, you may find this useful:

**[10 Practical jQuery Style Switchers](http://www.net-kit.com/10-practical-jquery-style-switchers/)**

Comment: @fudgey: Thanks for that, i have updated with more options now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [Theme Switcher Widget](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/ThemeSwitcher) or even provide the [bookmarklet](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/developertool/) (for Firefox)?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use themeroller anyway? Try adding [themeswitcher](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/ThemeSwitcher) to the page in question and try.